# Static elements interactions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have the following code:

```
Enabled = (id) => {
  let removal = null;
  if (!this.props.disabled) {
    removal = (
      <span
        className="chipRemove"
        onClick={() => this.onDelete(id)}
      >
        x
      </span>)
    ;
  }
  return removal;
}
```

it works well, but linter is giving me:

```
jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions
```

How can I solve this error (according to `jsx-a11y`)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From Doc:

> Enforce non-interactive DOM elements have no interactive handlers.
>   Static elements such as `<div> and <span>` should not have
>   mouse/keyboard event listeners. Instead use something more semantic,
>   such as a button or a link.

Valid interactive elements are:

```
<a> elements with href or tabIndex props
<button> elements
<input> elements that are not hidden
<select> and <option> elements
<textarea> elements
<area> elements
```

Reference: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md

Answer (score 23):

resolve this error by providing ...role="button" and tabIndex

```
<div
  onClick={onClickHandler}
  onKeyPress={onKeyPressHandler}
  role="button"
  tabIndex="0">
 Save
</div>
```