# How to handle click on child element

Tags: reactjs

Why did this produce error when I'm doing a click event on a child element here? It also produced an error when I attached `onClick={this.handleChangeCity} in the`"cities"` class

I would love to hear how you get around this.

Eslint error: [eslint] Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener. (jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events)
[eslint] Static HTML elements with event handlers require a role. (jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions)
(JSX attribute) onClick: any

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jsonData from "./navigation.json";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  loading: true,
  cities : jsonData.cities,
  currentCity: jsonData.cities[0].label,
};

this.handleChangeCity = this.handleChangeCity.bind(this);
  }

  createCities(){
    //let cityList = [];
    let children = [];
    let cityClass = 'oneCity';
    let activeCityClass = `${cityClass} active`;
    this.state.cities.forEach((city, index) =>{ 
      let divClass = index ? cityClass : activeCityClass;
      children.push(<div 
        onClick={this.handleChangeCity} ===> error when this is added
        className={divClass} 
        data-city={city.label}
        key={index}>{city.label}</div>)
    });

    return children;

  }
```

I'm not sure why this is happening...

```
  handleChangeCity = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    this.setState({
      currentCity: event.currentTarget.key
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (

      <section className="container">
        <div className="navigation">
          <div className = "cities clearfix">
               {this.createCities()}

          </div>

          <div className="underline"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Include the specific error you get and the line it occurs.

Comment: @Jayce444 just added

Comment: **For those, who encounters this issue when trying to make interactive div as button**.  
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576350/6119618  (Add both onClick and onKeyDown)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274507/6119618  (Add role="button")
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380207/6119618  (Add tabindex)
4. https://dequeuniversity.com/tips/tabindex-positive-numbers (positive tab index)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well it looks like you got 2 linting errors. First is `Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener.`. That looks like it's about accessibility, so people can use keyboard *and* mouse to interact. So you have to add a key handler too, check out [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575674/how-to-add-a-keyboard-listener-to-my-onclick-handler).

The second issue is `Static HTML elements with event handlers require a role.`. This is a linting option which prevents binding of event handler to generic things like a `<div/>`. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225468/static-elements-interactions) for an answer to that.

Alternatively, you could change or disable your linting so these are no longer issues.

Comment: actually I added both, but there was still an error...yeah I also used `div` and that could be the issue, but it's alright

Answer (score 2):

These are linting issues as mentioned in ESLint documentation as following:

> Enforce onClick is accompanied by at least one of the following:
> onKeyUp, onKeyDown, onKeyPress.

To fix this you can use any of the above mentioned props and change your code to this:

```
<div 
   onClick={this.handleChangeCity}
   onKeyDown={this.handleChangeCity}
   className={divClass} 
   data-city={city.label}
   key={index}>{city.label}
</div>
```