# How to fix 'button' interactive role must be focusable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, eslint

I have list of dropdown options which user can select.

optinos in dropdown are made with tag: < a href>:

```
<a onClick={() => handleSelect(filter)} role="button">
   {filter.name}
</a>
```

Problem is cus I must add `tabIndex="0" or -1`, to fix error from Eslint.

But When I add `tabIndex=0`, my button does not work anymore.

Is there are any other way to fix this error?

This is how looks dropdown component:

```
<ul name="filters" className="dropdown">
    {filterOptions.map((filter) => (
      <li
        key={filter.id}
        defaultChecked={filter.name}
        name={filter.name}
        className={`option option-${filter.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'}`}
      >
        <span className={`option-${filter.selected ? 'checked-box' : 'unchecked-box'} `} />

        <a onClick={() => handleSelect(filter)} role="button">
          {filter.name}
        </a>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Buttons are interactive controls and thus focusable. If the button
>   role is added to an element that is not focusable by itself (such as
>   `<span>`, `<div>` or `<p>`) then, the tabindex attribute has to be used to
>   make the button focusable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role#Accessibility_concerns

> The HTML attribute `tabindex` corresponds to the attribute `tabIndex` in
>   React.

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

So I think @S.. answer is correct:

```
<a 
  onClick={() => handleSelect(filter)} 
  role="button"
  tabIndex={0}
>
  {filter.name}
</a>
```

Answer (score 15):

Add a tabindex:

```
<a onClick={() => handleSelect(filter)} role="button" tabIndex={0}>
    {filter.name}
</a>
```

Comment: Note that setting a tabIndex greater than 0 can cause issues and is not advised since it will place those items ahead of the default focus order. For more details see [MDN Understanding the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Keyboard) and [Don’t Use Tabindex Greater than 0](https://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html)